# In what occupations, niches, roles can a software developer work when he is 90 years old?

Tags: retirement

I'm about 40 years old and I'm a software developer (with focus on Java). I was told that in my region (German-speaking Europe) companies stop hiring people over the age of 45.

I don't believe in public pension systems and assume that in order to survive when I'm old, I'll need to work until I die. It's doable because one of my ancestors also worked in an intellectually challenging job until the age of 89.

I intend to use the time until I'm 45 in order to acquire resources that will allow me to earn enough money in a role where I can continue working as long as I perform (not when some HR bureaucrats think I'm young enough).

**In what occupations, niches, or roles can a 45+ person work without being discriminated because of his age?**

Ideally, this niche should allow me to work remotely because I want to settle down in a rural region when I'm old. Both being an employee and a contractor is an option for me.

Below you can find my ideas on how this can be achieved. Feel free to criticize them (if one of them is terribly wrong, please tell). Note that these options are not mutually exclusive (I may use several of them at the same time).

**Option 1: Pick a niche where the demand is likely to be so high that employers/customers will hire by merit**

I assume that the rule "We don't hire anyone over 45" applies only, if the company doesn't need that developer badly enough. Let's say a company offers a job, and 100 qualified people stand in line for an interview. In this case, they can be picky and only hire young people.

If, on the other hand, the demand for that particular skill set is so high that their recruiters have to hunt down qualified candidates (it's recruiters who court the qualified candidates, not the other way round), then the age may be a lesser problem.

Hence, part of the solution is to

- pick a niche where the demand is likely to stay high in the coming years and
- establish myself as an expert in this niche (learn the technology and create proofs of my skills like a portfolio).

Most of my experience is with Java. I don't think I can work in Java when I'm old (see also *Option 2* below for an additional reason). So I need to pick another niche.

So far I think that frontend development with JavaScript **or** one of its subniches (like React or Angular.JS) may have a consistent demand during the years to come (more than Java does).

Why?

It's primarily medium and large corporations that need Java developers. These companies also have the age-discriminating HR gatekeepers.

In contrast, anyone, from a Fortune 500 corporation to a mom-and-pop internet store needs a developer who can make their web site work properly (frontend development). I assume that smaller companies care less about my age, especially, if I work for them as a freelancer.

Another reason in favor of frontend tech: Java is an established, mature technology. There are solutions for the majority of problems.

Frontend technology, on the other hand, changes rapidly and there is a lot of chaos in this sphere. In the frontend world I can deliver additional value to the customer by helping them orient in that chaos. For example, I could blog about which technology in 2018 you should use for task X and why. Such a blog post would a) help the potential customer make a technical decision and b) promote me as an expert. In 2019 I would write another article with the same topic and it is very likely that the contents will be different (because by then the advice from 2018 would have become obsolete).

**Option 2: Pick a niche in which employers/customers are used to remote work**

As I said, when I'm old I want to settle down in a small village. Most companies that use Java are located in big cities and, according to my experience with German-speaking companies, 99 % of them don't like remote work (I know that in other cultures, e. g. in US, remote work is much more widespread).

My impression is that there are more frontend-related remote jobs (including freelance) than Java-related.

Therefore I could increase my chances of finding employers/customers by focusing on niches populated by more remote-friendly companies.

Note: I don't consider working for US companies remotely because of the time difference. Correct me, if I'm wrong (i. e. if you know someone in the US who **successfully** works with a remote developer in Europe without them both being online simultaneously for 6+ hours per day).

**Option 3: Become a superconnector**

This approach focuses on expanding my network. For example, if I

- contribute something valuable to a promising open-source project,
- write a valuable blog post, or
- translate some material from English to German

I'm likely to get to know new people. The more people I know, the easier it is to provide value to them by connecting two people who may be useful to each other. The more such favors I do, the more likely people will want to respond in kind and help me get jobs (or get past the age-discriminating gatekeepers).

If these efforts go really well, I may find something like a virtual user group where I would regularly hold free webinars (e. g. on topics in frontend development), provide value for the customers, and position myself as an expert (which again increases the likelihood of getting hired). This would also increase my attractiveness to potential customers despite my age.

Comment: Have you considered that, no matter what you can do or plan now, at 90 years you won't be able to be "mentally flexible" enough to face the challenge of a contractor job?  Also, Java technologies may be mature and well estabilished, but they will surely change in the next 40 years ...

Comment: _companies stop hire people when they turn 45_ - really? Where I work (DE) we hire people regardless of age. What counts is what they can - as with every one else. Just stay up-to-date with the innovations and you'll be fine.

Comment: Google COBOL developer vacancies. There are *very* few young developers with that skill set, but it is still in demand some places. Even if Java becomes obsolete, it has been used by so many places for so long you will still be able to find work with it in decades to come (when the kids have moved on to the Next Big Thing). Of course, you can and should try to stay up to date. But don’t be ashamed of what you already know.

Comment: @Liquid Re *Have you considered that, no matter what you can do or plan now, at 90 years you won't be able to be "mentally flexible" enough to face the challenge of a contractor job?*: I personally know some freelancers who freelanced at the age of 50+. I knew two people who had a clear head at the age of 90. It is doable, provided that you pay attention to your health. There is no guarantee, of course. But there is no guarantee that the pension system will continue to work, either.

Comment: @red-shield I was told about the 45-years rule by a headhunter who I tend to trust. This applies to Austria.

Comment: '*I don't believe in public pension system*'. Right, but you are contributing to it (and have for the past 25 years). So the second step is to move to a country where you do not have to take that burden upon you and can save the money yourself instead (maybe in gold bars or army cans?). The first step is of course to try to claw some of those past contributions back. A bank heist followed by an exodus to Mali or the Central African Republic seems like a plan. You might try to use your remaining days in Germany to ask advises about the trip to those that have done it in the other direction.

Comment: You may not believe in a public pension system but haven't mentioned private pensions. Are you explicitly ruling out investing in a private pension while you work and retiring before 90 to live off that pension?

Comment: @user189035 - If you'd have the slightest clue, you wouldn't mock him. The socialist states will collapse sooner or later, and up to that point the burden they cause on the population will continually increase. Just recently I argued why socialism along with high state power (and therefore low individual liberties) is highly destructive and how the results of communism or anything getting close to that are in line with it. It's like nobody learned anything from the 20th century. Orwell's 1984 is not an instruction manual!

Comment: @Will No, I don't rule out private pension or investment vehicles like life insurance. I would evaluate such options from the standpoint "Will they continue to generate money in case of a global financial catastrophe (e. g. US dollar no longer bein a reserve currency)?". A US government bond may or may not be worth something, if such crisis happens. On the other hand, gold and the ability to write code in Java or JavaScript will probably still have value, even if the stock market collapses. I prefer to invest in something that wouldn't lose value in a financial catastrophe.

Comment: @Battle I agree with you. The German pension system was designed (and worked well) for a situation when there is one retiree per 3-4 working people. Low birth rates and prolonged life spans may reverse this -- there may be one working person "feeding" 3-4 retirees.

Comment: _companies stop hire people when they turn 45_ - I have been told the same (UK) since the 1980's but when I was made redundant in 2016 (age 54) it took 3 days from submitting my CV to an agent (Monday morning) to having a job offer with a "blue chip" international company (Wednesday afternoon).  I write embedded software.

Comment: @Franz Drollig - I am younger than you, however I do not plan on ever getting retirement money (out of the money I am forced to pay anyway). I just looked up [this](https://dieunbestechlichen.com/2017/08/acht-millionen-steuerzahler-bezahlen-die-ganze-party-deutschland-wann-kippt-das-system/) (German) just to confirm what I heard... so... I don't plan to create a family in Germany or to stay for too long. It's simply not worth it.

Comment: @FranzDrollig without getting diverted into an economic argument, I think it's quite an unusual assumption to rely on to consider all liquid asset classes that might contribute to a retirement income - stocks, shares, bonds, currency, and property included - as vulnerable to global financial collapse (of course they are) in a way that the value of your own labour as a software engineer is not. It is a bit of a distracting element of the question, and isn't necessary. Why not just say "I have determined I want to remain in work until I die" and keep the question about how best to achieve this?

Comment: @Liquid That's just ageist nonsense as spouted by people too young to know better. OK, I'm not quite 90 yet, but since I was 70 I've learned the equivalent of a couple of graduate-level science and engineering subjects from scratch - just for fun. And unlike most kiddies of so-called "working age", I've got the stamina to work for 16 hours a day 6 days a week, and no distractions from partners, kids, elderly relatives who need looking after, etc, etc!

Comment: It is a bad assumption - it basically leaves nothing else than committing suicide. If you want to be safe from economic collapse, you must make yourself someone who can benefit from it - trader, investor, something in this area. Career change. Otherwise you can not rule out all asset classes. And relying on something as crappy as life insurance - man, you NEVER will reach your goal. YOu must look into things that have a chance to go significantly up in value, who cares what happens in 20 years (beause hey, you buy X today does not mean you own it in 10 years).

Comment: @alephzero I'm happy for you if you are so energetic and you're fine working 16h a day, but my "ageist nonsense" is a statistical fact, as most people don't get "more stamina" growing older. I wish I will be as active and "fresh" when i'll hit 90y, but that's unlikely.

Comment: @alephzero - you're lying, plain and simple. People at 90 years of age can barely keep awake for 16 hours, they need multiple power naps to get through the day. Unless you are an absolute outlier on the order of 1 in a billion, you are simply making shit up.

Comment: Quite simply, if you are 85 and there is a situation where Germany doesn't have the money to pay your pension, then everything will be totally f***ed up and you won't get a job at 85, or 65, or 45, or 25.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Technology will be so different in that time span as to make any answer meaningless in terms of a specific tech and probably any specific niche within the dev industry. 45 years ago none of the languages you're using were even concepts.

So look at most people who have done it. Start a business or develop a product and then concentrate on building it so that it gives you a revenue stream until the end. Either by having a good exit strategy and selling it at it's peak for enough money or retaining ownership and picking the right people to keep it going while you collect your money.

I retired from working for anyone else before 40 and full time before 45, I have a revenue stream that will keep trickling into the foreseeable future which I nurture and add to while I keep my options open, I keep upgrading my skillset in several areas, but only really take on work for extra revenue and to stop from getting bored. Mostly I focus on increasing the trickle and having multiple ongoing revenue streams in case one fails.

You could do something similar. It's much the same as any long term investment, just that you back yourself to make it all work rather than others.

Pension here would not keep me in power, water, tea and bread without assistance, so I have no intention of relying on it when I get old enough. It's around the equivalent of USD $60 a month.

Answer (score 22):

None. The question is moot. With 90 it may be possible to still earn (I would consider this an amazing failure to savem oney, though), but the problem is you just said you are 45 and ask us for roles. Look BACK 45 years - IT Looked VERY different. Projections 45 years into the future are meaningless. You may end up between "architect" and "security" towards "archeologial pogramming on outdated systems" to "talk partner for new AI". WAY too far in the future to give any idea. Sorry, that just is too far into the future. I would not recognize today's technology 20 years ago.

Damn, you even name some technologies. And fall into the typical trap.

> So far I think that frontend development with JavaScript or one of its 
>   subniches

NONE of which have been around 30 years ago and now we get web assembly to run "any" langauge in a VM. Your assumption has zero merit 45 years into the future, sorry.

IF ANYTHING I would argue that SQL wil stil lbe around, because it survives, very few people know databases by heart and - hey, it actually is older, which can not be said of front end technologies.

With 45 you should be in your earnings prime. I am 49 now and I can tell you I have ZERO trust into the retirement system either. But as programmer you end up in the top paying area, if you are good. And if you are not, noone will hire you with 90 anyway. But, if you earn top money, you have no problem saving.

Comment: +1 I was working as a programmer in 1973, 45 years ago. A lot of my work was using overlays to slice and dice an assembly language program so it would fit in 16KB of memory, even after the OS had taken a few KB. The main editing tool was an 029 keypunch. I wrote bigger chunks of code out in block capitals on coding sheets.

Comment: If you live in an area where there is work, the cost of living rises - with the rising cost of living, it becomes rather difficult to save. The idea that people can save what is necessary for retirement is not in the slightest realistic for the vast majority of employees.

Comment: Given that my customers are 900km away that is a non issue. Heck, my customers are in another country - I am where people earn little, but guess what, I demand normal rates. Also, the OP is not an average employee, he is a programmer. It does not really get better than good programmers these days. Plus he can actually go freelance - the amount of money you can make there makes most other professions blush. And that takes not into account developing a money making interest around programming.

Comment: @TomTom You may need a reality check. People moving into programming nowadays are not exceptionally well paid. - If you have the luck to live in a cheap country (the link in your profile suggests that you do) while charging international customers a lot for remote work, lucky you. - The majority are not in such a position. If you have a look at programming positions around Paris, you will find that they are not better paid than other engineering jobs. (And those are well paid relative to say hospitality.) Then tax, social contributions... - Good for life, but not for saving.

Comment: @DetlevCM You need oto read. The OP - with all his attitutes - is not MOVING into programming. And the majority are sheep. I.e. Paris - why would i WANT to work there? Comes back to pülay smart. I also do not work in Austria (baaad rates). My choice. I am where I am NOT because of trusting rules other people make for me.

Comment: Even for existing programmers, it will be hard to negotiate significantly higher wages in new positions unless his knowledge is extremely specialised. - The group leader salaries are also not that high in Paris. And why Paris? Why not? - Its the place I know, but the same principle applies to Amsterdam, London - or any other place that offers work and a decent quality of life. Then there is the question whether customers want people to work on site or not (apparently favoured a lot in Ile-de-France.)

Comment: But supposedly by your own wirds it is shitty paid net and expensive. Ergo why live there? Oh, I am going where iH ave little money != smart decision. And changing jobs is HOW you earn more money actually. And specialization is something you can get. See, it all runs down to "own your finances" not "be a sheep and just trot along". if Paris s not worth it - it is not worth it. Same reason I do not work in London. Crappy pay, and even 800 pound I got offered daily are not worth it compared to the costs. If you limit yourself to france - grats. Welcome in not earning.

Comment: @TomTom There is more to life than just money. Maybe you'll realise that one day. Oh, and jobs in Paris are well enough paid to live, just don't expect to get rich from it - which is the standard rule for the vast majority of the world's population. Honest work does not make you wealthy - anywhere.

Comment: And maybe you realize one day that unless you want to live a crappy life at the bottom of the food chain, EARNING MONEY IS ABOUT MONEY. I personally love my life. Nice wife, nice card, nice hotels. And no "what the heck happens to me when I retire".

Comment: @DetlevCM - straight out of college programmers get salaries that are 2-3 times higher than what people make in most industries with 10 years of experience. If those people can live just fine off of their income, programers have no excuse.

Comment: @Davor Not in Europe. Whether you are looking at programming jobs or other post-graduate jobs, salaries are extremely similar and in most places are lower relative to the cost of living than they were a few decades ago. Add to that, the difficulty of obtaining a job in the first place (a mixture of lack of desired jobs and company pickyness). - And then there is the topic of cost of living: Where salaries increase, the cost of living increases.

Comment: @DetlevCM - yes, in Europe. Europe is not a single village, where everything is the same. I'm in Belgrade, and complete beginners can get around 1k euros salary here, while national average is around 300 Euros. My friend is making 5k in Berlin, and she's 28 years old now, with around 5 years of experience. German average is 2300 Euros.

Comment: @Davos Then look at the cost of living in those cities. - And look at the salaries for other graduate jobs in the same location: They pay roughly the same, but the higher the salary, the higher the cost of living in the area. Of course a French village in the middle of nowhere is cheaper than Paris - but what does one do there? - Cities offer culture, be it museums, concerts and also good food. (The same goes for any country really.)

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that companies stop hiring people after 45. Some may, but it is definitely not the rule. At the company I work for in West Germany, there's plenty of programmers in their 50s and 60s and they don't have much trouble getting another job in the region, as has been proven multiple times.

However, being so good that they can't ignore you is always a good rule to abide by.

Regardless of what you think or do, you should implement Option 3 immediately.

I wouldn't put too much money on Option 2. Web technologies will change like the wind. Last year it was React, this year it's Vue. Last year Javascript was king, this year Go. And so on. If you want to surely bet on something, go with native mobile - I mean, start from the hardware up, not from the software down.

Answer (score 3):

Consider freelancing. I have done this 5 or 6 times in Germany over the decades, several of those times being over the age of 45.

Yes, alas, there is age prejudice, not just in Germany, but everywhere. But, it seems only to apply to permanent staff, and not to freelancers/consultants/contractors (Freiberufliche).

I imagine that companies don’t care so much about people whom they have no legal obligation to employ. Since trade unions are so strong in Germany, the situation is more serious, with some permanent being literally unsackable.

I am in embedded software, not java, and I can see there always being a call for that, especially as IoT takes off. I would try to position yourself towards networking, not just desktop stuff.

I seldom have problems finding work, plus I have been able to travel the world for decades, choosing where I wanted to work. If you don’t want to travel, you should probably be based near a large city, to have a pool of potential client companies.

My contracts tend to last 12 to 18 months, although some have been much longer. It depends on the size of the project. If I do well, I am generally invited to stay on for the next project, as I know the companies tools and processes, plus they would rather have someone they know than replace me with an unknown quantity.

I have certainly known many contractors over 45 who have been with a company of more than ten years and no one cares about their age, because they are “only contractors”.

Experience ought to help you continue to find work, and a series of 12 to 18 month contracts will provide you with a much wider variety of experience than staying at one company, with the bonus that it keeps your brain sharp.

Finally, you might consider starting your own company. That way, no one can fire you :-)   We are only at the start of the beginning of the rise of IoT, so you might get into that. Personally, I have done side projects where someone has a business with a requirement for some software or an idea for a project, which we can also sell to others. I code for 50% of the company and he gets the other half for known the market and bringing in customers.

Think more out of the box, not just a permanent employee.

Answer (score 0):

**Without sounding cliché: software development.**

Although some modern companies like [IBM appear to have age discrimination issues](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2018-09-17/ibm-is-being-sued-for-age-discrimination-after-firing-thousands), older developers can still find work in industries that still use old or obsolete technology. Companies tend not to always update their software or even hardware at times (for example, [some SCADA systems still use Windows 95](https://www.bnamericas.com/en/news/ict/dated-windows-sottware-the-weak-link-for-scada-systems/), and [COBOL is 50 years old and still in use](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2009/apr/09/cobol-internet-programming)), and if a company sinks a lot of money into custom piece of software, they'll generally keep using it in order to increase their return on investment (even if better technologies exist).

With stronger legal protections, odds are that protections against age discrimination will improve over time. However, to cast aside your concerns, you might want to consider the fact that, as morbid as it sounds, *you might not live to see 90*, and stressing about a future that no-one can really predict is not beneficial. You could have all your plans in place and then an unexpected event occurs. You might grow bored of software development and change job occupations.

If you're reaching an age you're seeing it difficult to land a job, it might be worthwhile looking for an obscure language (the future's equal to COBOL), learning how to develop in it and applying to jobs that relate to it.

Comment: When I worked in Hidesheim about 2015 there was great demand for Cobol programmers with one of the large car companies (I forgot which), maintaining a legacy app which ran everything. Three failed major rewrites later they gave up & are sticking with the Cobol system. It's maintenance work & extremely boring, so it is very highly paid, to try to attract people

Comment: Problem is that today’s 45 year olds are unlikely to know COBOL.

Comment: @gnasher729 They can always learn. But in truth in the future, it might be Java is the 'new' COBOL (or any other language 45 year olds already know). Adobe Flash as a technology is already basically obsolete, and yet it's still relied upon.

Comment: @SSight3 You would seriously recommend that an older developer should learn an obsolete language? What nonsense. I learn _new_ things to be a step ahead of the kiddies and I plan to keep doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I am pushing this to also see what others think. You stated that you are currently a software developer primarily with JAVA. Why could you not state your are a domain expert who used JAVA to solve specific problems.

```
i.e. Business Analyst in the specific domains you currently work
within, be that medical, financial, whatever.
```

Wouldn't transitioning to a BA role or, if possible SA role (solutions architect) be a long-term solution.
SA is no longer involved with specific technology or language.

A BA is now out of tech. And a BA with years of experience in a specific niche is valued.